# solr - How can I exclude from the result the multivalue fields that don't match my query?

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene, dataimporthandler

I have some indexed documents like the one above:

```
{
  "doc_desc": "Indexing Child Documents in JSON",
  "doc_id": "379",
  "image_id": [
          "28086# ho hum... this is page 1 of chapter 1",
          "28087# more text... this is page 2 of chapter 1",
          "28088# more text... this is page 3 of chapter 1"
      ]
}
```

When I query for “ho hum” I need that the document returned be something like:

```
{
      "doc_desc": "Indexing Child Documents in JSON",
      "doc_id": "379",
      "image_id": [
              "28086# ho hum... this is page 1 of chapter 1"
       ]
}
```

So I can know the exactly page that have the words i was searching for. How can i do that?

In other words... How can I exclude from the result the multivalue fields that don't match my query?

OBS: I am using solr-4.10.2 and a data-import (db-data-config.xml) from my SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not without a lot of manual tinkering.

Two possible solutions is to index each page as a separate document, or use [the Block Join feature of Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers). The first option is probably the quickest to implement.

Comment: I can't find how to create separate documents for each page using data-import. I just found how to do it using json. Do you have some tips?

Comment: @user5590 Sorry, I don't have any good idea for how to do it directly in your import handler. You might have success with doing it in an UpdateProcessor, though.

Comment: @user5590 Depending on what you need the content for, you might also be able to get what you need using the highlight module when querying.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to index de page instead of the documents.